# MongoDB slice and project array of embedded documents

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to slice an array of embedded documents and project the result so only a certain field is returned.

For example, I can do this to return only the "myField" element in "myArray":

```
db.myCollection.findOne({"name": "test"}, {"myArray.myField": 1} )
```

And I can do this to slice "myArray":

```
db.myCollection.findOne({"name": "test"}, {"myArray": {"$slice": 1}}
```

I'd like to do both but can't seem to manage; any tips?

Comment: `db.myCollection.findOne({"name": "test"}, {"myArray": {"$slice": 1}, "myArray.myField": 1}})`

Comment: @Alex Blex Just curious. Does this work ? Is it documented somewhere ? I would expect `{"myArray.myField":: {"$slice": 1}}` to work but this doesn't.

Comment: @Veeram, why it shouldn't? OP confirms both projections work in isolation, and I see no reason why it shouldn't work in a single query. Does it return an error? I didn't test it tbh.

Comment: @Veeram is it a typo with double colons that doesn't work?

Comment: @Alex Blex yeah it is a typo. Your projection works and mine doesn't. So it have me thinking what is the exact behavior and was hoping it was documented somewhere for us to use the projection in a certain way.

Comment: Yes, it is not possible to do in a single query like that, which is why I asked

Comment: @jramm, define "not possible". Does it result with a syntax error? Unexpected result?